# one to many relationship definition in ttl and SPARQL-Generate nested GENERATE

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

I have too many things that I'm not sure of, I may not have asked the right question.

I want to use 
https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/playground.html
to map some JSON data to turtle RDF format.

Here is a working a version, with the problematic part commented out:

```
BASE <http://example.com/> 
PREFIX iter: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/iter/>
PREFIX fun: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/fn/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX crm: <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/>
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
PREFIX cocoon: <https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.ttl>

    GENERATE { 
      [] a cocoon:VM;
        rdfs:label ?name;
        cocoon:numberOfCores ?cores;
        cocoon:hasCPUcapacity[
            a cocoon:PhysicalQuantity;
                cocoon:numericValue ?gceu;
                cocoon:hasUnitOfMeasurement cocoon:gceu;
        ];
        cocoon:hasMemory [
            a cocoon:PhysicalQuantity;
                cocoon:numericValue ?memory;
                cocoon:hasUnitOfMeasurement cocoon:GB;
        ];
    #    GENERATE { 
    #        gr:hasPriceSpecification [
    #            gr:UnitPriceSpecification;
    #                gr:hasCurrency "USD"^^xsd:string;
    #                gr:hasCurrencyValue ?regionalPrice^^xsd:float;
    #                gr:hasRegion cocoon:?region;
    #        ];
    #    }
    #    ITERATOR iter:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".price") AS ?price .
    #    .   
    }
    SOURCE <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/master/example/jq/gcloud/vm.json> AS ?source
    ITERATOR iter:JSONPath(?source,"$[*]") AS ?gcloudVM
    WHERE {
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".name") AS ?name)
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".cores") AS ?cores)
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".memory") AS ?memory)
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".gceu") AS ?gceu)
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?price,".price") AS ?regionalPrice)
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?price,".region") AS ?region)
    }
```

The ontology I defined https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/ontology.ttl

Assuming it is correct, my problem is the nested `GENERATE`.

I want to annotate

```
"price": [
  {
    "region": "us",
    "price": 0.0076
  },
  {
    "region": "us-central1",
    "price": 0.0076
  }
]
```

Maybe into something like:

```
gr:hasPriceSpecification [
    gr:UnitPriceSpecification;
        gr:hasCurrency "USD"^^xsd:string;
        gr:hasCurrencyValue 0.0076^^xsd:float;
        gr:hasRegion cocoon:us;
];
gr:hasPriceSpecification [
    gr:UnitPriceSpecification;
        gr:hasCurrency "USD"^^xsd:string;
        gr:hasCurrencyValue 0.0076^^xsd:float;
        gr:hasRegion cocoon:us-central1;
];
```

Full data is at
https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/blob/master/example/jq/gcloud/vm.json

Comment: to be honest, you should use their mailing list to ask about this specific tool. chance might be much higher to get an appropriate answer, I don't know how many people here ever used this tool or even heard about it

Comment: Perhaps the "04 - NestedGenerate" example would help. Also, perhaps you need `a gr:UnitPriceSpecification;`, not `gr:UnitPriceSpecification;`. @AKSW, [Antoine Zimmermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260887/antoine-zimmermann) is a [contrubutor](https://ci.mines-stetienne.fr/sparql-generate/team-list.html).

Comment: I know, I saw the list. but still I think mailing list give a direct support. bz the way, the nested GENERATE doesn't seem to work inside the blank nodes and simply needs a subject in the first triple pattern. Make a global blank node works: `BIND(bnode() as ?idx)` and use this in each GENERATE then

Comment: something like `GENERATE { 
            ?idx gr:hasPriceSpecification [
                    a gr:UnitPriceSpecification ;
                    gr:hasCurrency "USD"^^xsd:string;
                    gr:hasCurrencyValue "{?regionalPrice}"^^xsd:float;
                    gr:hasRegion ?region 
            ] 
        }
        ITERATOR iter:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".price") AS ?price .` seems to be more correct. still the question whether the JSONPath pattern, I didn't try it

Comment: Miranda, AKSW is right: the mailing list is more likely to give you quicker response. I 'm watching the tags "sparql" and "semantic-web", so I would have eventually seen your question, but with the mailing list, we can have a conversation sending mails back and forth as much as necessary to get to the solution. BTW, the link to the `.ttl` file your provide leads to a 404. For completeness of the question, you should add a valid link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw) is right, I got rid of the syntax error.

```
BASE <https://w3id.org/cocoon/> 
PREFIX iter: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/iter/>
PREFIX fun: <http://w3id.org/sparql-generate/fn/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX crm: <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/>
PREFIX gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
PREFIX cocoon: <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/master/ontology/1.0/cocoon.ttl>

GENERATE { 
  <data#{?name}> a cocoon:VM;
    rdfs:label ?name;
    cocoon:numberOfCores ?cores;
    cocoon:hasCPUcapacity[
        a cocoon:PhysicalQuantity;
            cocoon:numericValue ?gceu;
            cocoon:hasUnitOfMeasurement cocoon:gceu;
    ];
    cocoon:hasMemory [
        a cocoon:PhysicalQuantity;
            cocoon:numericValue ?memory;
            cocoon:hasUnitOfMeasurement cocoon:GB;
    ];
    GENERATE {
        <data#{?name}> gr:hasPriceSpecification [ 
            a gr:UnitPriceSpecification ; 
                gr:hasCurrency "USD"^^xsd:string; 
                gr:hasCurrencyValue "{?regionalPrice}"^^xsd:float; 
                gr:hasRegion "{?region}"^^xsd:string; 
        ] 
    } 
    ITERATOR iter:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".price[*]") AS ?price
    WHERE {
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?price,".price") AS ?regionalPrice)
        BIND (fun:JSONPath(?price,".region") AS ?region)
    }   
    .

}
SOURCE <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/master/example/jq/gcloud_vm.json> AS ?source
ITERATOR iter:JSONPath(?source,"$[*]") AS ?gcloudVM
WHERE {
    BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".name") AS ?name)
    BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".cores") AS ?cores)
    BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".memory") AS ?memory)
    BIND (fun:JSONPath(?gcloudVM,".gceu") AS ?gceu)
    BIND (fun:JSONPath(?price,".price") AS ?regionalPrice)
    BIND (fun:JSONPath(?price,".region") AS ?region)
}
```